# Looping in Underscore Template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

My JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    "datas": [
        [
            {
                "time": "08:00",
                "frequency": "daily"
            },
            {
                "time": "14:00",
                "frequency": "daily"
            },
            {
                "time": "20:00",
                "frequency": "daily"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

My underscore html looks like so:

```
<ul class="table-view">
    <% _.each(datas, function(schedule, key) { %>
    <li class="table-view-cell">
        <a href="#enter-reading/<%= key %>" 
           class="push-right"><%= schedule.time %></a>
    </li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Here is the entire html that is printed on render:

```
<ul class="table-view">
    <li class="table-view-cell">
        <a href="#enter-reading/0" class="push-right"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, expected result - your datas has 1 el inside its array and this array contains objects replace datas with datas[0]

Comment: your `datas` is not a simple array, is an array of arrays. you need two nested `_.each` to access the schedule.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I put the looping into a named variable and passed that in and now all is working as expected.  If you want to submit this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **datas** is array with only one element - array with models. 
You have to update your template replacing **datas** with **datas[0]**, or store it in var and pass it into loop

```
<ul class="table-view">
    <% _.each(datas[0], function(schedule, key) { %>
    <li class="table-view-cell">
        <a href="#enter-reading/<%= key %>" 
           class="push-right"><%= schedule.time %></a>
    </li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```